# Create custom sharable data within a microsoft graph api event

Tags: post, microsoft-graph-api, custom-data-attribute

Currently, I'm creating a new event by using the ms graph api with **user_1,** **user_2** can accept this event and also receives the event.

MS graph api Events endpoint:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events

**Problem:**
I would like to be able to add custom data to the event, created by user_1 which user_2 can also retrieve, and the other way around.
The custom data is a stringified object containing data about the appointment created.

So far, I tried different options to add the custom object within the event as:

- `open extensions`
- `extended properties`
- store my custom data within the `transactionId`

Open extensions and `transactionId` didn't work, because only the creator can see data posted here. **User_2** couldn't see any of the custom information created by **user_1** and the other way around, according to the ms graph support this is how it's supposed to be working.

Extended properties didn't work because I couldn't add a custom object, besides that I would need to know exactly what I want to retrieve when getting the event with the extended properties, and this I do not know.

None of the options seemed to work so far, even though I feel like it should be easy:
Add a custom stringified object to the ms event with **user_1**, retrieve the same event with **user_2**, the event should contain the stringified object as well and not be null.

Using `bodyPreview`, `body` or `content` is also no option. Since the user will see my stringified object when they receive an invitation email.

I just wouldn't know where to store this custom stringified object within the ms graph event body, which is also shareable between multiple users. From all the properties given by the ms docs, I couldn't identify which one to use, which is also shareable between users.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0

Any tips are appreciated!